# VBS FindNext method of range class failed

Tags: excel, vbscript

Hello just some Quick help on this subject with `.Find method` in

It always loop back to the same first cell it found , now with `.findnext` (*first cell address*) i get an error saying *FindNext method of range class failed*

Any help will be greatly appreciated here is what i have so far:

```
Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set EffR = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\March Eff Report.xlsx")
objXLApp.Application.Visible = True
objXLApp.DisplayAlerts= False 
Set CPS = EffR.Sheets(3)
Set MTDsum = EffR.Sheets(4)
Set DIMA1 = EffR.Sheets(5)
Set DIMA2 = EffR.Sheets(6)
Set CP2 = EffR.Sheets(7)
Set CP3 = EffR.Sheets(8)
Set AO500 = EffR.Sheets(9)
Set AO501 = EffR.Sheets(10)
DIMA1.Activate

findMe = "7001030025F" 
Set rSearch = DIMA1.Range("A1")
Set rFound = rSearch.Find(findMe)
adrFirst = rFound.Address
'wscript.echo ""&adrFirst&""
rSearch.FindNext(adrFirst)
```

Comment: You need to deposit the result of `FindNext` into a Range.

Comment: Ur comment also helped me cause it was straight foward and right at the same time. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several comments:

- You are only searching a single cell, so I presume your code should be looking at a longer range (it can only find one match).
- You need to cater for not finding a match.
- Updated code below.

*code*

```
Set rsearch = DIMA1.Range("A1")

Set rfound = rsearch.Find(findMe)
If Not rfound is nothing Then
wscript.echo "found"
    adrFirst = rfound.Address
Do
Set rfound = rsearch.FindNext(rfound)
Loop While rfound.Address <> adrFirst
else
wscript.echo "not found"
End If
```

Comment: Hey there are more than one recurrence for the data thats being searched , the rest of the code i know i can write but just this specsific part isnt working "never used .findnext"  however i used what you wrote and same result. same error

Comment: So i just made some modifications and like mentioned with ur first comment i needed to list the range , the reason why i used "A1" alone is with .find with the range "A1" normaly searched the whole sheet with my other scripts, thank you again